# How many triples of distinct students picked from 200 students?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Mr. R is looking to create a committee of 3 students. The Committee is to be made up a President, Vice President, and Secretary. If there are 200 students that he can pick from, and no person can serve two positions, how many possible committees are possible?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**

1. In how many ways can you choose a president out of the 200 seniors?
2. Once you have a president, in how many ways can you choose a vice president *out of the remaining 199 seniors*?
3. Once you have a president/vice president, in how many ways can you choose the secretary *out of the remaining 198 seniors*?

Answer (score 0):

Because the order is important, then 
$$n=P(200,3)=\frac{200!}{(200-3)!}=200*199*198$$